# Is it possible to run java commands during a batch process?

Tags: java, postgresql, batch-processing, bulkinsert, sql-insert

What I mean is I have a program that executes inserts in batches of 100k.  Each one of these inserts is assigned a new ID from a sequence on insert.  I want to keep the batch process for obvious reasons, but I also need to then pull out each ID as it is created and do things with it before I move on to the next insert.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not extremely knowledgeable in PostgreSQL, but is there a way for your prepared statement to return the key? I'm using a MySQL DB with a Jdbc connection, and the syntax is `PreparedStatement pstmt = JdbcDB.getConnection().prepareStatement("SQL GOES HERE", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);` The important part is the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. Note `JdbcDB` is just a wrapper class I've created. `getConnection()` returns a `java.sql.Connection`.

Comment: That does help a bit, I didn't realize that was an option, and it's something I was looking for.  However, even if it returns keys, is there a way for me to do things with that key in java before the batch process moves on to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Things work differently in PostgreSQL than MySQL.  First you have to write your insert as:

```
INSERT INTO foo (...) VALUES (...)
RETURNING id;
```

The `RETURNING id` is important as that tells the insert statement to return something.  Then you should be able to pull back the id as what you could expect from a select statement.

I am not quite sure how the JDBC driver for PostgreSQl implements this regarding batch processing though.  If you have to, you could probably modify this to store the id in a temporary table or something that you could query from after.